# "Message sent to deallocated instance" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I'm optimizing an old app for iOS 7, and have to deal with non-ARC code, with which I have never dealt before. The trouble is with in-app purchases, with the library MKStoreKit. The app is using an old and modified version of it. I can't use the newer version, because there is no access to the server.
The line of code, which is causing an error is:

```
[MKStoreManager sharedManager];
```

The error itself is:

```
-[MKStoreManager retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x145e6ba0
```

I used NSZombie, this is what I got:
[image]

So, any help would be greatly appreciated. I've already spent three days, trying to solve this problem.

UPDATE:
MKStoreManager.m:
http://pastebin.com/ZppTkxmN

MKStoreManager.h:
http://pastebin.com/TJVM7UdN

The line, causing the error:
[image]

Comment: Do you get this error when you call sharedManager? Do you have source code of that modified version of MKStoreKit? 3 days seem enough to learn non-ARC, you know retain-release stuff, right?

Comment: I've updated the question with MKStoreManager code. I have a basic knowledge of non-ARC, of course, but it seems, that it is insufficient.

Comment: I suggest adding Exception Breakpoint from Breakpoint Navigator. It will show you which line throws that exception. sharedManager method looks like a valid method.

Comment: I've already tried it. Updated the question with the screenshot.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint in `sharedManager`? It looks like the @synchronized in `allocWithZone:` could be causing deadlock. I would just switch this code out with the Apple-recommended GCD singleton pattern.

Comment: @AaronBrager, thanks, but I've tried to use singleton pattern and it doesn't help. The same error appears.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you download the ARC Version of MKStoreKit from this link and replace the new library in your project and have fun.

https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit

Hope it Helps.

Comment: As I told before, I cannot use a new version of the library, because there are too many changes in it, and the server can't work with it.

Comment: @igrekde What you can do is, Add -fno-objc-arc tags to these NON ARC files in the Build Phases of your project. It will work :)

Comment: It doesn't work, because the app uses third-party server for in-app purchases. The server code is suited for an old version of the library.

Comment: How the third party server affects the NON-ARC code files. I am seriously not able to figure out.

Comment: Have you run analyzer? Did it find any problems?

Comment: @RajanBalana My bad, the problem is not with the server. The code of my version is modified by the previous programmer, and these changes are strongly linked with the application's code. I've tried to use a newer version, but it seemed to me, that fixing this error would be a simplier solution. There are too many differencies between these two versions of MKStoreKit.